# Can i use WebResourceLoadDelegate for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi I want to change a cookie for iOS app, so I found with

```
– webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:
```

but I always get "Cannot find protocol declaration for WebResourceLoadDelegate".
I have added the WebKit.framework and the WebResourceLoadDelegate.h and the error is still there.

please, I need to change the cookie from a URLRequest. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This API exists on OS X only. It does not exist on iOS.